# Checking arguments before calling a function known to check arguments itself

Tags: c, function, styles

This is rather a matter of code style and traditions, I guess, but the question is as follows.

Let's suppose we have a function which checks arguments, for example:

```
int do_something(int * arr) {
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("arr is NULL\n");
        return -1;
    }
    ...
```

Now we are going to use it. **The question is**: should we check an argument we're going to pass to it? For it will check it anyway.

The example is rather simplistic, real life scenarios may be much more difficult, with more arguments (and more complicated checks) and more additional overhead ensuing from calling a function - if this is, say, some kind of IPC.

So more general question is: what are common guidelines and practices as regards to such situations?

Comment: There is only one answer: it depends.

Comment: You should probably do reasonable tests in the caller. If the called function is in the same translation unit (or LTO is used), the duplicated test can be optimized away by the compiler, and if the called function is *not* in the same translation unit you should not have to check more than the function prototype to be able to call it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz but what should I pay attention to and consider, then?

Comment: The circumstances. Your real-life circumstances.

Comment: @olegst it really depends on the circumstances. Usually you put lots of [`assert`](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/assert)s in your functions so problems can be catched early during debugging.

Comment: This is a [*"design-by-contract"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) question. The pre- and post-conditions defined for your function will help you make the call. In many instances, checking on both sides (sanitizing your inputs) is a good design practice to minimize the risk of the caller not abiding by the contract.

Comment: Sorry, I do not think it's a good design practice to check things on both sides. It is the result of a bad knowledge of the interfaces. It is a kind of sloppinnes, that often adds clutter to the code, making the code less readable. If the caller or the callee do not know even the syntactic requirements, it is not a redundant check here or there that will save you from semantic mismatches. Sorry if I sound a bit harsh, but sharing one big project with a colleague who is always doing these unnecessary checks all the time gave me plenty of occasions to see how it is contra-productive.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be based on personal experience and bias. Regardless, here it goes:

1. If `do_something` belongs to a library and is exposed to users of the library as a function that they can call directly, it is best to have any and all checks necessary to make sure that `do_something` is robust.
2. If it is an internal function in a library, it is still best to have any and all checks necessary to make sure that `do_something` is robust. The only exception I would make and not do the checks is if the performance of the program/library is adversely affected by the checks.
3. If it is a function in your own application, it is still best to have any and all checks necessary to make sure that `do_something` is robust. The only exception I would make and not do the checks is if the performance of the program/library is adversely affected by the checks.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is documented as checking the parameter then call it without the check. For example `free()` is explicitly documented as accepting `NULL` as parameter, there is therefore no point in writing the too often seen

```
if(p != NULL)
  free(p);
```

It's cluttering your code for no benefit. The gains of avoiding unnecessary calls is generally completely drawned out in the noise.

Of course, you would have to check the return value of your function.

If you are the implementer of your function, be it a library function or just a local helper function, it is even possible to annotate on certain compilers the specific contract of your function.

If for example, your function does not accept a `NULL` pointer, you can set (on gcc) an `__attribute__((nonnull))` at the declaration of the function.

If you declare for instance:

```
int do_something(int * arr) __attribute__((nonnull (1)));
```

you would know that you cannot call the function with `NULL` (and the compiler would even warn if it knows that you do). But be careful, that attribute can be surprizing by moments. If you declare it like I did and you would still check the parameter as you do in your example, then you could discover that the optimizer completely removes the check from the object code.